# How to limit width of MenuItem in JavaFX2 context menu

Tags: java, javafx-2, contextmenu, menuitem

How to limit max width of `ContextMenu` or force text wrapping of the MenuItem's content? There is no such property on `MenuItem` and setting pref/max/min width on the `ContextMenu` seems not to work.

```
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    contextMenu.setPrefWidth(200.0);
    contextMenu.setMinWidth(PopupControl.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    contextMenu.setMaxWidth(PopupControl.USE_PREF_SIZE);
    contextMenu.getItems().add(new MenuItem("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `MenuItem` has a default inner `Labeled` component for showing the text set through `MenuItem.setText()`, and it seems you have hard way (like using `Node.lookup()` by the CSS id selectors) to reach that `Labeled` and manipulate it. Luckily the other way around is more easier and don't hurt at all I think. The other way is to use `MenuItem.setGraphic()`:

```
Label lbl = new Label("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua");
lbl.setPrefWidth(50);
lbl.setWrapText(true);

MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem();
menuItem.setGraphic(lbl);

contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the CSS style for the ContextMenu using:

```
    ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
    menu.setStyle("-fx-max-width: your-width-value;");
```